# .index.get_loc returns TRUE/FALSE instead of integer. Can tell me how to get the index in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I created two different dataframes (DF1 from a CSV file and PSE0 from TXT file).

When I use the .index.get_loc function to get the index (row number) of a value in the dataframe, DF1 would return the correct row number while PSE0 returns TRUE and FALSE.

Code below:

```
PSE0=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(PSE_DES,str(Sht1['K4'].value)),delimiter='\t')
PSE0=pd.DataFrame(PSE0,columns=['RIC','EFFECTIVE DATE','CHANGE TYPE','SEQ NUM','DISTRIBUTION AMOUNT'])

DF1 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(PSE_DES, Files), delimiter='\t')
DF1 = pd.DataFrame(DF1, columns=['RIC', 'IC', 'LOCAL PRICE', 'CS', 'DVD'])

for i in range(0,len(L1)):
    PSE0.set_index('RIC').index.get_loc(L1[i])
    DF1.set_index('RIC').index.get_loc(L1[i])
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, there are two types of data that can be returned:

- if the index you're looking for is unique, you will get a single int-value

  `unique_index = pd.Index(list('abcb'))
   unique_index.get_loc('b')
   1`
- if there are multiple indexes with the same name, you will get an array with boolean

  `same_index = pd.Index(list('abcb'))
   same_index.get_loc('b')
   array([False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)`

So I guess, there is a moment where you have duplicates of Indexes, but I don't know at what point.